# Facebook Application Security Question

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I just created a Facebook Canvas application and I want this application to be added as a Tab to my company fanpage.

However I do not want anybody else to be able to do this.

I do however want users to be able to use the application.

How in the world do I configure my application for that?

And how do I even get it in as a tab without making it availiable to everybody?

I hope you guys can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't block people from adding your application's tab to their own tabbed profile.

However, you *do* know the Facebook ID of the user whose tab is being viewed (the tab's owner), so you can behave accordingly.

```
if ( $_REQUEST['fb_sig_profile_user'] == YOUR_FAN_PAGE_ID )
{
  // display the tab
}
```

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile#Application-Specific_Tabs